# How to make RSS fead reader for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rss

I was wondering if there were any good tutorials out there on how to make an RSS feed reader for eclipse. If you know any, or any really good RSS tutorials, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I doubt that enough people write an RSS feed reader to warrant someone writing a tutorial for it.  It's the ideal situation for a reusable library, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a tutorial: [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/) is a great RSS reader based on Eclipse. As it is open source, you might want to [inspect its sources](http://rssowl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rssowl/trunk/).